# Adding custom column to zipline to use it in handle_data

Tags: pandas, zipline, back-testing

I am facing some problem , i am using zipline to backtest data.
with the normal OHLC format everything works fine but I would like to be able to use other columns that are in my csv file apart from the one (open,close, high,low, volum) that zipline offers by default.
I have columns such as Marketcap, ev, pe and I would like to be able to use them in the handle_data function.

Answer (score 0):

The original Zipline and its derivates don't allow you by default adding custom columns at least you modify `zipline.data.bcolz_daily_bars`, `zipline.data.bcolz_minutes_bars` and so on since they write their library with immutables global variables.

For instance in [Zipline reloaded](https://github.com/stefan-jansen/zipline-reloaded/blob/4a648f6a0e7bf61d9bfe46f7152166cf1f13c5d8/src/zipline/data/bcolz_daily_bars.py#L39) you would find OHLC and US_EQUITY_PRICING_BCOLZ_COLUMNS which are declared as global variable as was mentioned before.

```
OHLC = frozenset(["open", "high", "low", "close"])
US_EQUITY_PRICING_BCOLZ_COLUMNS = (
    "open",
    "high",
    "low",
    "close",
    "volume",
    "day",
    "id",
    "marketcap" # <- new variable
)
```

and are used in other places in order to prepare for saving and reading with bcolz.

So, if you modify those places you should receive the market capital as you want.

```
 @expect_element(invalid_data_behavior={"warn", "raise", "ignore"})
    def to_ctable(self, raw_data, invalid_data_behavior):
        # ***
        processed["marketcap"] = raw_data.marketcap.astype("uint32")
        return ctable.fromdataframe(processed)
```

However, a simpler approach is declaring the variable in the ```initialize`` function.

```
def initialize(context):
  context['AAPL'].marketcap = marketcap
```